# Google BigQuery's WITH not compiling

Tags: google-bigquery, google-query-language

I am trying to run a query with a `WITH` clause in BigQuery. Even trying to run a very simple one like

```
WITH randomquery AS (SELECT * FROM example_table)
SELECT user FROM randomquery;
```

results in a compilation error:

> Error: Encountered " "WITH" "WITH "" at line 1, column 1. Was
>   expecting: EOF

Even copy-pasting the example query from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/query-syntax#with-clause) produces the same error. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you deselect `Use Legacy SQL` under `Show Options`? CTEs are only available with BigQuery's new, more standard SQL dialect (currently in beta).